# Oracle forms: Rollback an item to database value without changing form

Tags: oracle, validation, builder, oracleforms

Let's say if some condition is fullfilled, it shouldn't be possible to make any change to my entire block. I've found a simple way to do this:

In the 'WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM' trigger on blocklevel, I've written this statement:

```
begin
    if (-- custom statement -- 
            and :system.record_status <> 'QUERY' 
            and get_item_property(:system.current_item,DATABASE_VALUE) <> name_in(:system.current_item)) then
        msgbox('Can''t change');
        copy(get_item_property(:system.current_item,DATABASE_VALUE), :system.current_item);
        raise form_trigger_failure;
    end if;
end;
```

The copy statement sets the item value back to database value. But the problem is, that the status of my form will go to 'CHANGED', while there actually is not really a change visible, since the item got rollbacked to the database value. So when I try to exit the form, the system asks me if I want to save my changes. And I don't want that to happen. How can I change this?

Comment: Why are you then putting `copy(get_item_property(:system.current_item,DATABASE_VALUE), :system.current_item);` into if statement when condition is satisfied. Put it in `else` block so that this `copy` action take place only when there is some change\

Answer (score 0):

To avoid asking to User if want to save or not values, you can perform Key-Commit

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE_TRIGGER('KEY-COMMIT');
 standard.commit;
END;
```